# How to come up with solutions like this?(To check whether a sudoku is valid or not)

Tags: c++, sudoku

https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/valid-sudoku/
The problem was to determine whether a sudoku is valid or not

To solve this problem only 3 rules need to be checked as stated in the problem.

1. Each row must have the numbers 1-9 occuring just once.
2. Each column must have the numbers 1-9 occuring just once
3. And the numbers 1-9 must occur just once in each of the 9 sub-boxes of the grid.

So I thought for a while and came up with a solution similar to this:
This was not a big deal as a hash for row was done in first ,then a hash was maintained for column and lastly for the submatrix.

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isValidSudoku(vector<vector<char> > &board) {
        // Start typing your C/C++ solution below
        // DO NOT write int main() function
        map<char, bool> row;
        map<char, bool> col;
        map<char, bool> block;

        for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
            col.clear();
            row.clear();
            for (int j=0;j<9;j++){
                if (board[i][j]!='.'){
                    if (col[board[i][j]]){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        col[board[i][j]]=true;
                    }
                }
                if (board[j][i]!='.'){
                    if (row[board[j][i]]){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        row[board[j][i]]=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int ii=0;ii<9;ii=ii+3){
            for (int jj=0;jj<9;jj=jj+3){
                block.clear();
                for (int i=ii;i<ii+3;i++){
                    for (int j=jj;j<jj+3;j++){
                        if (board[i][j]!='.'){
                            if (block[board[i][j]]){
                                return false;
                            }else{
                                block[board[i][j]]=true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }       
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

However I later looked into some codes and I found this:

```
Class Solution
    {public:
        bool isValidSudoku(vector<vector<char> > &board) {
            // Start typing your C/C++ solution below
            // DO NOT write int main() function
            vector<vector<bool> > rows(9, vector<bool>(9, false));
            vector<vector<bool> > cols(9, vector<bool>(9, false));
            vector<vector<bool> > blocks(9, vector<bool>(9, false));

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
                    if (board[i][j] == '.') continue;
                    int c = board[i][j] - '1';
                    if (rows[i][c] || cols[j][c] || blocks[i - i % 3 + j / 3][c])
                        return false;
                    rows[i][c] = cols[j][c] = blocks[i - i % 3 + j / 3][c] = true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    };
```

As you can see this is a pretty neat solution ,but the striking part for me was "blocks[i - i % 3 + j / 3][c]", My question is how do you make such an expression "i - i % 3 + j / 3" for a subarray?As far as my knowledge there wasn't a general formula for accessing a 3X3 matrix from 9x9. If someone could give general rules to make neat codes like this ,I will be more than happy.

Comment: Do you understand the modulus operator?

Comment: Yes I do. I just don't understand how he came up with a formula

Comment: BTW, consider training on Topcoder or USACO. After several weeks of training that would seem to you like a very easy task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would like to get a function from `(row, col)` to block number. Here's a map of results we would like to see

```
000 111 222
000 111 222
000 111 222
333 444 555
333 444 555
333 444 555
666 777 888
666 777 888
666 777 888
```

Let's look at the first line. Such repetitive structures come from integer division. So, if you try `col / 3`, you'll get exactly the first line.

Now let's look at the whole table. Let's substract that first expression from all the rows, so it will show all `A[row][col]` such that `A[row][col] + col / 3 = block_no`.

```
000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000
333 333 333
333 333 333
333 333 333
666 666 666
666 666 666
666 666 666
```

Hey, it doesn't depend on column number anymore. If you divide that by 3, you'll see the structure we;ve just worked with, and decide you'll need `row / 3`.

So, all together: `col / 3 + 3 * (row / 3)`.

The part on the right looks very much like an operation "round down to the nearest multiple of 3". It could be achieved in another way: you can subtract all that is over that nearest  multiple. It's exactly what modulus operator does. So we can simplify it to

`col / 3 + row - row % 3`.